# WebClient does not expose downloadFile()

Tags: web-services, mobile, windows-phone-8

Hello i started learning Windows phone platform, I 'am tring to use existing service to download zip file over Http protocol. I've seen examples etc that are using System.Net.WebClient class and call downloadFile() but in my case such method does not exist ! Theres only DownloadStringAsync() available. Can any one give me some tips how to download that file ?

Comment: What methods *do* exist on that object?  I suspect there's an `OpenReadAsync()` which can be used to get the raw stream of the response content, which you can then save as a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET 4.5 framework for Windows Phone only supports a sub-set of the frameworks features and methods. That's why you don't see a DownloadFile method.

Comment: I figured it out yesterday eventually :)